# Organize total thread size in multiple Thread Executor Pools in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to organize the amount of total thread in a spring application. The project is old and a lot of different developers have created thread pools to execute there threads to speed up processes in different places. But somehow the overall management is missing.

As we all know the size of the server hardware does not grow automatically with the amount of work it has to process. There is a hard limit given by 'Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()'.

With one thread pool one can set the 'corePoolSize' and the 'maxPoolSize' by using the availableProcessors value.

One strategy would be to have the policy: "One pool is enough". All different tasks would get the same pool instance and queue up if the amount of maxium threads is reached in the pool. That avoids unnecessary thread managament and keeps the single processes fast.

Another strategy I thought of would be to have a overall management instance where the different pools need to dynamically get a permission to start new tasks. So if pool A is busy with max amount of threads then pool B must wait until enough processor capacity is available.

Question: Is there some already existing technique to manage different pools for Java 8?

Comment: [`ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool--) might be a way to go?